# How to split words in Solr case-insensitive but keep the case in the result?

Tags: solr

At the moment I use solr.MappingCharFilter to split words by adding whitespaces before and after the word component

e.g.: "foo" -> " foo " 
splits "foobar" into " foo bar"
but "Foobar" would not match the mapping and will not be splitted

but now i also need to split them case insensitive but keep the case in the result. 
is there any way to achieve that 
"foo" -> " foo " will split "FooBaR" into " Foo BaR" ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use WordDelimiterFilter for this use case. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterFilter for more details, and specifically the "splitOnCaseChange" flag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is not realy what I am looking for. (or only a part of what I need)

Comment: You're using the wrong filter to split words is what I am saying. From the docs (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CharFilterFactories#CharFilterFactories-solr.MappingCharFilterFactory) MappingCharFilter is mainly used for character mapping "for example, for normalizing é to e".

Comment: I know this a quite peculiar approach.
But what i need is something where I can define a list of words (like "foo", "abc" and it will add withespaces around this word where ever it finds them but keeps the original case.

Comment: Have you looked at DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter then? I think it should cover your use case. In reference to your original example, just adding "foo" to the dictionary should do (provided you also have a LowerCaseFilter enabled). Have a look here for more details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Language+Analysis#LanguageAnalysis-DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter

Comment: thanks again for your comment, but with DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter you need do add "foo" and "bar" to your dictionary to split these components, but i need something that splits "foo" from possible String, not only from the words in the dictionary.

Comment: Well no actually, it will still work if you only have 'foo' in the dictionary. So when you search for 'foo' it will retrieve results with 'foobar', 'bazfoo' etc. in them (this is what you are trying to achieve, right?)